# ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; Unable to create table using foreign key

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am new to mysql-python and referring [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-ddl.html).
Following is my query-

```
TABLES['doctor_details'] = (
                                "CREATE TABLE `doctor_details` ("
                                 " `dr_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
                                 " `doctor_link` varchar(40),"
                                 " `doctor_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,"
                                 " `doctor_exp_years` float,"
                                 " `doctor_qualification` varchar(40),"
                                 " `doctor_phone_no` varchar(15),"
                                 " `doctor_city` varchar(40),"
                                 " `doctor_state` varchar(40),"
                                 " `doctor_country` varchar(40),"
                                 " `doctor_speciality` varchar(40),"
                                 " `doctor_website_link` varchar(40),"
                                 " `status` int NOT NULL,"
                                 " PRIMARY KEY (`dr_id`)"
                                ") ENGINE=InnoDB")

        TABLES['hospital_details'] = (
                                "CREATE TABLE `hospital_details` ("
                                "  `hospital_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
                                "  `dr_id` bigint NOT NULL,"
                                "  `hospital_link` varchar(40),"
                                "  `hospital_name` varchar(40),"
                                "  `hospital_address` varchar(40),"
                                "  `hospital_city` varchar(40),"
                                 "  `hospital_state` varchar(40),"
                                 "  `hospital_country` varchar(40),"
                                 "  `hospital_phone_no` varchar(15),"   
                                 "  `hospital_speciality` varchar(40),"
                                 "  `doctor_link` varchar(40),"
                                 "  `hospital_website_link` varchar(40),"
                                "   PRIMARY KEY (`hospital_id`)"
                                "   CONSTRAINT `dr_idfk` FOREIGN KEY (`dr_id`)"
                                "    REFERENCES `doctor_details` (`dr_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION" 
                                ") ENGINE=InnoDB")
        self.cursor.execute( TABLES['doctor_details'])
        self.cursor.execute( TABLES['hospital_details'])
```

And it gives me following error-

*ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT `dr_idfk` FOREIGN KEY (`dr_id`)    REFERENCES `doctor_details` (`dr_i' at line 1*

Apologies if I am doing some silly mistake but guidance / help in any form is welcome.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma after this line

```
PRIMARY KEY (`hospital_id`)"
```

so it should be

```
PRIMARY KEY (`hospital_id`),"
```

Then again, I don't do Python, so it all looks Greek to me.

Comment: @Drew- THANKS A LOT IT SOLVED MY ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): Sorry for being so stupid !

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark the Answer as answered with the green check mark (or any other answer), when you are happy.